# How to gunzip files recursively (or how to UNDO 'gzip -r')

Tags: files, gzip

I am learning Linux and I was trying the gzip command. I tried it on a folder which has a hierarchy like

```
Personal/Folder1/file1.amr
Personal/Folder2/file2.amr
Personal/Folder3/file3.amr
Personal/Folder4/file4.amr
```

I ran
    "gzip -r Personal"
and now its like

```
Personal/Folder1/file1.amr.gz
Personal/Folder2/file2.amr.gz
Personal/Folder3/file3.amr.gz
Personal/Folder4/file4.amr.gz
```

How do I go back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
gunzip -r Personal
```

which works the same as

```
gzip -d -r Personal
```

If `gzip` on your system does not have the `-r` option (e.g. `busybox`'s gzip) , you can use

```
find Personal -name "*.gz" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 gunzip
```

Comment: I changed my working directory to "Personal" and ran "gunzip -r Personal" and got this result
"gzip: Personal.gz: No such file or directory"

I do have the -r option because I used it to compress my files

Comment: As you used `gzip -r Personal` to compress it, you can run `gunzip -r Personal` from the *same* place  to decompress it. If you are inside the `Personal` directory, you need to run `gunzip -r .` instead (`.` is the current working directory).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer:

Change directories until you're just one step up from the target directory and run this command

```
gunzip -r Personal
OR
gunzip -r .     <--- if you're in the same directory
```

. is the current working directory

Thanks @jofel

Comment: This should be an edit on _jofel_'s answer not a separate answer which adds almost nothing to the existing one...